# How to merge row according to the value in 2 different column in linux or R

Tags: r, linux, dataframe

I have a data.frame:

```
  Gene.ID Chr Strand Start End Gene.Name Transcript.ID
1 ENSMUSG00000025917               1     -1      10024601    10024978                Cops5                    ENSMUST00000027050
2 ENSMUSG00000025917               1     -1      10024843    10025063                Cops5                    ENSMUST00000190155
3 ENSMUSG00000025917               1     -1      10027103    10027251                Cops5 ENSMUST00000190155 ENSMUST00000186528
4 ENSMUSG00000025917               1     -1      10030599    10030710                Cops5 ENSMUST00000190155 ENSMUST00000186528
5 ENSMUSG00000025917               1     -1      10032339    10032424                Cops5                    ENSMUST00000186528
6 ENSMUSG00000025917               1     -1      10033258    10033323                Cops5                    ENSMUST00000186528
```

I want to merge it in this way:
If the Gene.ID, chr, strand and Gene.name are same, and also stop of first row is bigger than start of next row merge these 2 rows and keep start from first row as start and for stop keep the max value from stop of first row and next row. And also keep Transcript.ID from both row.

The expected result is:

```
Gene.ID                          Chr Strand         Start         End            Gene.Name                         Transcript.ID
1 ENSMUSG00000025917               1     -1      10024601    10025063                Cops5 ENSMUST00000190155 ENSMUST00000027050
3 ENSMUSG00000025917               1     -1      10027103    10027251                Cops5 ENSMUST00000190155 ENSMUST00000186528
4 ENSMUSG00000025917               1     -1      10030599    10030710                Cops5 ENSMUST00000190155 ENSMUST00000186528
5 ENSMUSG00000025917               1     -1      10032339    10032424                Cops5                    ENSMUST00000186528
6 ENSMUSG00000025917               1     -1      10033258    10033323                Cops5                    ENSMUST00000186528
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may want to consider [bedtools intersect](http://bedtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/tools/intersect.html?highlight=intersect). Also, you may get better answers if you ask your question over at `BioStars.org`

Comment: I have did it before with bedtools intersect but could get result. Do you know how can I do it by bedtools? Thanks for your suggestion..

Comment: Yeah, intersect isn't right. Maybe bedtools merge. Like I said, try biostars.org. All bioinformaticians over there. It is a worth a look through all the bedtools documentation though. You will end up using a lot of it eventually.